# Getting the bounds of annotation having custom view

Tags: ios, annotations, mapkit, mkannotationview

I have a number of pins on my map and I want to know the coordinates of top-left and bottom-right corners of their views to perform specific manipulations with them.

Here is the code where I need to insert the code getting the bounds of specific annotation view:

```
- (void)mapView:(MapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {
    if ([view.annotation isKindOfClass:[PlaceAnnotation class]]) {
        PlaceAnnotationView *placeAnnotationView = (PlaceAnnotationView *)view;
        // How to get the bounds of placeAnnotationView here?
    }
}
```

Related issue: [How to adjust region to fit custom annotation callout that have just appeared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13095911/how-to-adjust-region-to-fit-custom-annotation-callout-that-have-just-appeared)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just posted an answer to the question this question originates from. The answer may be found there: [How to adjust region to fit custom annotation callout that have just appeared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13095911/how-to-adjust-region-to-fit-custom-annotation-callout-that-have-just-appeared)